# How I Can Extract an Object Property of an Object Array in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

#### Code Example:

```
interface Object1 {
  property1: string;
  property2: Array<Object2>;
}

interface Object2 {
  property1: string;
  property2: number;
}
```

If I have an array of `Object1`, how I can get an array of `object2's` `property2`.

For example:

Is there some method to do this in typescript?

Comment: Could you please clarify the question a little. I'm not sure if I follow the question you are asking? Are you asking how to make an array of "number" created from obj 2? 

(Ps: I don't specifically know typescript, but I know OOP so I might be able to help if you clarify)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's this?

```
let objectTwos: Array<number> = 
    objectOnes.reduce((accumulator, current) => accumulator.concat([current.property2.property2]), []);
```

Comment: Maybe should be `let property2Array: Array<number>`

Comment: Why i cant use `let objectTwos: Array<number> = objectOnes.map(obj => obj.property2);`?

Comment: Because you wanted object2's property2. What you have will return Array<Array<Object2>>.

Comment: No, objectOnes is an Array. Array doesn't have a "property2", an object that is stored in the objectOnes does.

Answer (score -1):

**If you want to extend the object you can use the following**

```
interface Object1 {
  property1: string;
  property2: Array<any>;
}

interface IObject2 {
  property1: string;
  property2: Array<number>;;
}

interface IObject1 extends IObject2 {
    property1: string;
    property3: boolean;
}
```

Just remember you can't cast Property2 as an Array then recast it to a number.

here's the [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) documentation for typescript